# how to change background color of android icon in cordovan application

Tags: android, cordova

Hello i am developing an application using cordova for android.

i have used an icon as below in the screenshot

[image: app icon I'm using now]

I am trying to change the background color from the default white to a black.

this is what I am trying at the moment

```
https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/12.x/config_ref/images.html
```

```
Create a res/values/colors.xml resource file in your project directory to store the app's colour definitions.

<resources>
    <color name="background">#000000</color>
</resources>

<resource-file src="res/values/colors.xml" target="/app/src/main/res/values/colors.xml" />
```

I have all files in their required locations locations

after compiling I keep getting

```
ERROR:/Users/##########/Documents/cordova/celebapp/platforms/android/app/src/main/res/values/themes.xml:3:5-8:13: AAPT: error: resource color/cdv_splashscreen_background (aka com.famakin.Celebritysporty:color/cdv_splashscreen_background) not found.
```

please help

Answer (score 0):

I solved the background issue by placing the logo on another background of choosing..

e.g I need ed a black background to show at the back of the icon.

i create a bigger background and place the logo on it